# Wordpress 5.0.3 | Images not resizing correctly

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to resize images on [this page](https://milkandmotherhood.com/2016/10/interview-with-rachel-i-didnt-really.html).

They have exactly the same properties and code but the first one is has `width: auto`.

This is the code of the first image (baby boy):

```
<div class="wp-block-image">
  <figure class="aligncenter is-resized">
    <img src="https://milkandmotherhood.com/wp-content/uploads/418900_10152030658650634_1604957331_n.jpg" alt="baby boy sleeping" class="wp-image-821" width="512" height="540"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Here's the code of the second image (family):

```
<div class="wp-block-image">
  <figure class="aligncenter is-resized">
    <img src="https://milkandmotherhood.com/wp-content/uploads/414572_10101518238988742_677706630_o.jpg" alt="Family on the meadow smiling" class="wp-image-822" width="512" height="341"/>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Both are the same, yet the first image has `width:auto` at the webpage.

What should I change?

Comment: How do you want to resize it? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Delete "width:auto" ? Otherwise you're going to have to explain what do you mean by "resize".

Comment: The width is set to 512 px for both images (see the code). But for the first image the width: auto CSS rule is applied. Both images are resized and formatted in the same way but they are displayed differently. I can’t delete the width: auto, because it’s inherited. It just shouldn’t be applied as I specified width: 512px. You can see that when you inspect the images.